# How can a Spring Boot REST API communicate with an API behind an user's router?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot

I'm currently building a REST API with Spring Boot. The idea is that users can have a "component" which can send and receive data to and from my API, I make the assumption that it has access to Wi-Fi via the user's router. A component has to implement certain endpoints that I define.

My REST API works similarly as something like "If This Then That". It supports three things: a component can send data to the platform, the platform can send actions to a component and the platform can request data from a component.

[image: Communication between a component and a webserver.]

Currently I have the API (which is pretty far feature wise) and a dummy component I made in NodeJS which mimics a "real" component. The dummy component currently does a POST request to the platform with data, which the platform then checks for certain values. The platform can request data from the dummy component through a GET request and does a POST request to the component to perform an action.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to implement the communication between the platform and a component. I assume that there isn't much trouble with sending a POST request from a component to the web server, but I think that there's more trouble with doing a POST and GET request from the platform to a component.
  My web server and dummy component currently both run on localhost. I currently define the IP address of the component, which the platform then uses to perform POST and GET requests on. This works fine for now, but when a component is behind a IP address outside localhost I assume that there's going to be trouble with firewalls and such, since a component is connected to the public web via an user's router.

Now my question is as follows: what is the best way to communicate with a component outside the network of the web server via HTTP.
  For me the logical answer seems like web sockets, but should I be thinking about a different option? My knowledge of networking is limited to HTTP and sockets, so I would like to hear what others think and what I should research.

Thanks for reading!

Edit:
For reference this is the code I use to do a POST request from the platform to a component, I use Spring's RestTemplate for this:

```
DebugResponse responseToReturn;
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(userComponent.getAddress() + restPath, request, String.class);
            responseToReturn = new DebugResponse("Post Success");
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            responseToReturn = new DebugResponse("HttpClientError");
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            responseToReturn = new DebugResponse("HttpServerError");
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            responseToReturn = new DebugResponse("RestClientException");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseToReturn = new DebugResponse("Generic POST exception");
        }
        return responseToReturn;
```

userComponent.getAddress() contains the IP address (localhost in this case) and restPath contains the path to send the data to (/action in this case). "request" has some JSON data it sends to the component. The dummy component uses Node's request library to send data to the IP of the platform.

Comment: Yes, I would go with `HTTP`. Usually, every router allows http therefore you won't have any struggle. Also the HTTP communication is clearly defined.

Comment: Won't I run into trouble when trying to do a GET or POST request to a "component" that's connected to a wireless router due to potential firewalls or ports that are closed? My current implementation of doing a GET or POST request from the platform to the IP address of a component seems a little too easy.

Comment: On a normal configured firewall (company internet access), port 80 and 443 are most probably not closed as this is the main communication channel for most applications. Of course, in the end it lies within the power of the system administrator.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll see if I run into trouble when I start testing components outside my localhost.